# Jenkins Pipeline build step - getBuildVariables() returns empty map

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following code in a test Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
    stage 'Build'
    def job1 = build 'Sample_Freestyle'

    def dur = job1.getDuration()
    println dur

    def vars = job1.getBuildVariables()
    println vars

    def myMap = [k1:'v1', k2:'v2', k3:'v3']
    println myMap
}
```

As I understand it, when I use the build step a RunWrapper object is returned. I am trying to get the build variables of my test job named "Sample_Freestyle", which at them moment runs a simple Windows batch command:

```
echo "Hello World"
```

Whenever I run this, it executes correctly, however I'm left with an empty map. I tested the getDuration() method and that returns as expected. I took a look at the RunWrapper class [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-support-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.java) and it may be that env is null (circa line 212), but that's only a hypothesis.

Does anyone know why I would be getting an empty map when calling getBuildVariables()? Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: Is `Sample_Freestyle` a parameterized job?

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone was searching for a solution in declarative pipelines.
I wanted to grab downstream job env variable (multibranch declaritive pipeline)
My downstream job sets an environment variable as part of it's build.

So it my upstream I do this:

```
//downstream job kickoff
def buildResult = build job: "<downstreamjob>"
//downstream sets a new env variable env.PACKAGE_NAME
def packageName = buildResult.buildVariables.PACKAGE_NAME
```

Comment: For anyone reading this, this is the only way i found to transfer upstream env variables.

Comment: FYI this will work only if the downstream is finished with Success. Otherwise, 'buildResult' is null and you will be calling 'buildVariables' on a null object.

Answer (score 2):

getBuildVariables() returns the job's user-defined parameters, not the job's environment variables such as WORKSPACE or BUILD_TAG.

Based on Vitalii's comment, I did an experiment and added a parameter to the Sample_Freestyle job. When I added a test string parameter the map was no longer empty! I got:

```
{TEST_PARAMETER=Test Parameter}
```

I suggest the method name be changed from getBuildVariables() to getJob*Parameters*() or getBuild*Parameters*() for consistent naming.

Comment: This is not correct, and is a very confusing answer to come across if you're trying to get env vars from downstream jobs. https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html#getBuildVariables--  You are also unable to alter params using `params.TEST_PARAM` during a build.